# Strict aliasing violation and analysis

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I understand violations to the strict aliasing rule could lead to many troubles. One of them is some kind of "register-cache/memory incoherence". The following code is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <numeric>


struct F { float x, y; };


int main()
{
  int input;
  std::cin >> input;
  std::cerr << "\n";
  int size = input;
  
  
  constexpr int cap = 4;
  int64_t z[cap]; 
  size = size > cap ? cap : size;
  std::iota(z, z + size, 0);
  
  
  std::cerr << "Initial z[] = ";
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) std::cerr << z[i] << ", ";
  std::cerr << "\n\n";
  
  
  // Type punning, undefined behavior.
  F *f = (F*)z;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    f[i].x = 3.14 * (i + 1);      
    f[i].y = 3.14 * (size - i);
  }
  
  
  std::cerr << "After writing floats z[] = ";
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) std::cerr << z[i] << ", ";
  
  
  while(true);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile the code using gcc-8.3 (mingw64),

```
system("C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -std=gnu++17 -Ofast -o Ofast.exe tmp2.cpp")
```

on a 64-bit Windows 10, Intel i9-9980HK, this is the output:
[image]

After writing floats, `z[2]` is still 2, which is wrong but expected.

The Standard states that any `char*` can point to a memory block pointed by other pointers of all types, thus reads and writes through that `char*` must be acknowledged correctly. So I modified the above code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <numeric>


struct F { float x, y; };


int main()
{
  int input;
  std::cin >> input;
  std::cerr << "\n";
  int size = input;
  
  
  constexpr int cap = 4;
  int64_t z[cap]; 
  size = size > cap ? cap : size;
  std::iota(z, z + size, 0);
  
  
  std::cerr << "Initial z[] = ";
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) std::cerr << z[i] << ", ";
  std::cerr << "\n\n";
  
  
  // Undefined behavior.
  F *f = (F*)z;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    f[i].x = 3.14 * (i + 1);      
    f[i].y = 3.14 * (size - i);
  }
  
  
  // The following branch is runtime dependent so cannot be pruned by an
  // aggressive but compliant compiler (ACC).
  // The goal is to make any ACC "fear" that z[]'s contents can be altered
  // via another char*.
  // This complies the strict aliasing rule since a char* can point to
  // any memory block pointed by another pointer of any type, and read / write
  // the memory thereafter.
  if(input > 2000000000) // Little chance to enter.
  {

    char dummy[cap * sizeof(int64_t)];
    int Nbytes = size * sizeof(int64_t);


    char *zchar = (char*)z; // Set a char* pointer to z[]
    std::memcpy(dummy, zchar, Nbytes);


    // Read and write zchar[], do some dummy arithmetics:
    for(int i = 0; i < Nbytes; ++i) zchar[i] &= zchar[Nbytes - 1 - i];
    int S = std::accumulate(zchar, zchar + Nbytes, 0);


    // Print it so this whole dummy thing cannot be pruned by ACC.
    std::cerr << "dummy result = " << S << "\n\n";


    // Recover.
    std::memcpy(zchar, dummy, Nbytes);
  }
  
  
  // Because the same memory block as z[] could be rewritten via a char*, 
  // the ACC has to achieve some sort of register-cache/memory coherence, 
  // thus the right output.
  std::cerr << "After writing floats z[] = ";
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) std::cerr << z[i] << ", ";
  
  
  while(true);
  return 0;
}
```

And the result becomes right:
[image]

I can even simplify the dummy branch to

```
if(input > 2000000000) // Little chance to enter.
{
   int S = std::accumulate((char*)z, (char*)(z + size), int(0));
   std::cerr << "dummy result = " << S << "\n\n";
}
```

And it still produces the right result.

Is my rationale regarding the strict aliasing rule correct? Is the above a valid way to prevent the "register-cache/memory incoherence" issue that could come with type punning?

Thanks!

Comment: _One of them is some kind of "register-cache/memory incoherence"_ What makes you think that?

Comment: why that strange system-call compile?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you have in mind when you say "*register-cache/memory coherency*".

The issue with the aliasing violation is simply (as with all undefined behavior) that the optimizer may choose to rely on it never happening (because it is UB) to infer constraints on the program execution and to use that to produce optimized machine code that needs to be functional only under these constraints.

For example in your case here without the write through `char*` the optimizer could for example see that the writes through `F*` could not possibly modify `z` because that would be an aliasing violation. Therefore it could e.g. reorder the writes through `F*` after the output.

Alternatively the compiler may see that `z` first has values written to it that can be calculated at compile-time, which it may remember for optimization. Then it can ignore the writes through `F*`, which are impossible due to UB, and finally seeing the output it can simply choose to output constants corresponding to the values it "knows" are in `z`.

Your method of protection might thwart some of these optimizations, but there will always be others that a compiler may choose to employ.

For example a compiler may recognize that the write through `F*` is UB and conclude from that the only possible value `size` can ever have is `0`, because the loop body may never be executed in a non-UB program.

It can then use that knowledge to optimize the whole program to:

```
int main()
{
  int input;
  std::cin >> input;
  std::cerr << "\n";
  std::cerr << "Initial z[] = ";
  std::cerr << "\n\n";
  std::cerr << "After writing floats z[] = ";
  
  return 0;
}
```

With your method you can only hope that a compiler doesn't at some point get complex enough optimization capability to make this determination (and I am not sure that there isn't currently a compiler able and willing to do so.)

If you want to make use of constructs violating the aliasing rules, then you need to make sure that your compiler doesn't rely on it for optimization at all. Compilers usually have a flag to tell them not to do so, e.g. `-fno-strict-aliasing` for GCC, although in your program it is not only the aliasing violation that is a problem, but it is also a problem that there isn't actually any `F` object or array of `F` objects on which you would be allowed to do pointer arithmetic or access members. I am not sure that GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag is generally sufficient to guarantee that it wont rely on these two kinds of UB for optimization.

---

As a side note: `while(true);` is also undefined behavior in C++ (but not C). You cannot have an infinite loop without IO, atomic or volatile operations.

For example, as long as the loop is there Clang 13 with `-O3` on compiler explorer outputs:

```
Initial z[] = 0, 1, 2, 

After writing floats z[] = 4690138725358302659, 4668251232723858883, 4632222435709990994, 4210784, 1, 12884901889, 2, 4200237, 140113662963656, 4200160, 0, 4200160, 0, 0, 0, 140113661087923, 140113662942080, 140736215914984, 4295040000, 4198848, 4200160, -8494071215197471174, 4198608, 140736215914976, 0, 0, 8494236860351561274, 8413707913860136506, 0, 0, 0, 1, 140736215914984, 140736215915000, 140113666830736, 0, 0, 4198608, 140736215914976, 0, 0, 4198654, 140736215914968, 28, 1, 140736215916259, 0, 140736215916270, 140736215916410, 140736215916436, 140736215916463, 140736215916489, 140736215916515, 0, 33, 140736217014272, 16, 529267711, 6, 4096, 17, 100, 3, 4194368, 4, 56, 5, 11, 7, 140113666637824, 8, 0, 9, 4198608, 11, 0, 12, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0, 23, 0, 25, 140736215915385, 26, 2, 31, 140736215916525, 15, 140736215915401, 0, 0, 0, -5663448171308038656, 2109109041276691562, 14696481348417631, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8391735729100685312, 4921308987509732720, 6436278639021083743, 8011689642975907935, 7597692896546878576, 7813877729437312364, 7020094974597624431, 3328210922030065518, 8011686456465305392, 7597692896546878576, 7813877729437312364, 7020094974597624431, 3328210922030065518, 4193470700803862320, 7885630528017166127, 8675390226550253936, 7147056913697434736, 3329058620635505004, 3918810539134823984, 5719376094260428852, 7150963379136975952, 8605359904538979439, 4707178968379521377, 5642809484591980366, 4427723895174544723, 5548561706083904609, 5283936564644036947, 8028914707716066895, 8320788952091016562, 5786948835902442496, 8026326388909754708, 7023201308806115180, 4415020012612383609, 8011672841536692527, 32420700043113589, 0,
```

and I don't know whether compiler explorer is truncating the output: https://godbolt.org/z/bcq5vKonG

Comment: The C Standard allows implementations intended to be suitable for low-level programming to, as a form of "conforming language extension", specify that various forms of pointer-related constructs will be processed "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment".  It doesn't officially recognize any category of implementations that do so, because suitability for any particular task is left as a "quality of implementation" issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.